# how can i show media controls for my music player website in the notification tray using javascript/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5-audio, audio-player

As you know from the title that I want to customize the notification for my music player website. default chrome notification only contains play/pause button.
is there any way I can customize it to add buttons like next/previous or my own custom buttons.

I would like to implement javascript or Jquery for this.

Here is the [website](https://anurag-shukla.000webhostapp.com/projects/Music/music.html) I am talking about.

Notification bar on mobile such as:

[image]
Thank You for any of your support.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31086320/html5-audio-player-next-and-previous-functions

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov I already have the controls on the website but not in the notification bar. I was asking help regarding this.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "the notification bar"?  Maybe a screenshot pointing it out.

Comment: @freedomn-m by notification bar , i mean the smartphone's notification panel where we receive the notifications.I attached the screenshot. Hope you understand.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't pick up that it was for mobile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the API you are looking for is the [Media Session API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Session_API). If you register the handlers for the appropriate actions the browser should display buttons which trigger those handlers.

```
navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('previoustrack', () => {
    // Whatever you need to do to play the previous track.
});
navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('nexttrack', () => {
    // Whatever you need to do to play the next track.
});
```