# Using Multimedia Keys to Change <Audio> Src

Tags: javascript, html

I have an audio tag, and three audio streaming sources.

Currently I have a button for each source, and I change the src using JS, however, I would like to have it so I can change the audio src using the keyboard multimedia keys, the MediaTrackPrevious and MediaTrackNext keys.

Adding a keydown event listener to the document is not helpful, because I want it to work even when the browser is minimized \ I am on a different tab.

By default the Pause\Play multimedia key is working, Is there a way to also make the Previous \ Next keys work?

Thank you.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also have a similar problem which was solved by using media session API.
[here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65132225/13991602)

edit:    [This](https://web.dev/media-session/) is the best post I've found in media session api and it is as easy as copy paste.

I can't make comments yet so writing it as an answer.